# How to get rid of the lock symbols on files which denies access when opened?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, encryption, lock, decryption

I have an external HDD, files within one folder are somehow encrypted due to a virus I assume.
 Whenever I try to read, copy, delete or even move the files within that folder it says access denied/permission denied.

Notice: I already have the administrator rights and full control to access everything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission issue - probably / hopefully not due to encryption and probably also not due to a virus...

If you've used the external drive on another computer, then it's possible that the folders were created / owned by a user on that computer which isn't present (or isn't "you") on this computer.

To restore access to everyone, try following these steps:

1. Try right clicking on the directory or file that is exhibiting this behaviour -> `Properties` -> Select the `Security` tab.
2. You might see entries like `S-1-5-21-298447237-1138007211-212633956-1000` where you would expect to see a user or group name - this is the SID, which is usually hidden from you.
3. Click `Edit` (UAC should pop up), click `Add`, and then enter `Everyone` and press `OK`.
4. Now select the `Everyone` entry, and check the `Full-control` / `Allow` check box, and press `OK`. This may take a while.
5. Click `OK` in the original properties dialog, and then try opening the directory / file again... you should be granted access.

If you feel like it, you *could* "tidy up" those unknown entries, but make sure you understand what you're doing.